# Consumption change calculation

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I want to calculate yearly consumption change according to the following formula:
$$C_{t+1}=C_{t}e^{x_{t}}$$
I need to calculate ${x_{t}}$.

I have the consumption data $C_{t+1}$ and $C_{t}$.

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of logarithms, $x_t=\ln {\dfrac{C_{t+1}}{C_t}}$